# Deleting var/log folder in magento 1.9 version

Tags: magento-1.9, log

Can we delete var/log folder from Magento-1.9?

Will it lead to any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete it, it doesn't create any problem......
By default magento generates 2 files called **System.log & Exception.log** files reside in `var/log` folder to track the errors.....

also you can **Disable** generating new log files using below configuration :

**System > Configuration > Developer > Log settings > Disable Logging**

If log files are generating means, it shows the errors/warnings, so that something wrong in the site, **instead of deleting** you should check the errors and try to **solve it** when you get free time....

Answer (score 0):

These folder have log files to track the errors, You can delete them it won't create any problem. If you want to stop further log generation you can disable it from admin. At below path

**System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Log Setting** and set **Enabled** to **No**